# SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, installation

I successfully installed SQL Server 2014, but when I look for SQL Server Management Studio it was not on the CD.

I have just downloaded SQL Server 2014 Management Studio separately and would like to get advice on any issues installing SQL Server Management Studio.

My experience with SQL Server 2005 was that the process installed both the server and the SQL Server Management Studio. Since they appear to be installed independently now. I would appreciate advice or a link to comprehensive documentation.

Comment: Try installing for me it went fine,if you get any issues,please paste here,we will try to help

Comment: What version and edition you downloaded ? Was it express editon, I might know what wrong you did

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the main installer, and choose to add the shared feature. The fact that it's available as a separate download as well is a bonus for people who don't want to have to download such a large ISO, but the SSMS installer is definitely part of the main installer - you just have to choose it from the "shared features" section.